# What to say when you don’t know the answer to an interview question?

Tags: interview

When you have no clue about the question, how do you answer/act when you do not know the answer at all? Telling the truth is pretty obvious. But how could you try to transform this weakness into a strength?

Comment: This question is not unique to software development and is thus off-topic as per the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 69, accepted):

"I don't know how to do that, but if I ran into that problem in a project, here's how I'd go about figuring out how to make it work..."

Comment: When I'm interviewing, one of the big problems I used to see  was programmers who wouldn't say "I don't know". Telling me that didn't hurt your chances (unless it was a lot).  And adding how you figure out it increases your chances. Not admitting you don't know ruins your chances.

Comment: @Jeff: Exactly.  When I interviewed at my current job, the boss explicitly asked me how I'd handle things I don't know.  I told him that if I know something then I know it, and if I don't, then I admit it and try to find out, but I don't try to BS people and make them think I know it when I don't.  He must have liked the answer, because I ended up getting the job. :P

Comment: @Jeff: In addition to this, follow up with a question!  If you just say "I don't know" and stop, I'm not as impressed.  If you say "I don't know, is that similar to x, y, z?" or "I don't know, can you explain more?"  At least I have a clue that you'd try to find out!  As an interviewee, a follow up gives you more info so that maybe you CAN give an answer.

Comment: +1 for including the phrase "I don't know". I am voting for this one instead of @ChaosPandion's answer because you immediately follow it up with some context and a plan for what's next. If I am interviewing someone and they are incapable of admitting that they have any weak spots anywhere then I am immediately less well-disposed towards them. A little humility goes a long way. That and a plan to overcome it. Just shrugging and saying "I dunno" and then nothing? Significant fail.

Comment: @Jay: Yes, follow-up earns bonus points. But no follow up with the admission is still leaps and bounds better than trying to fake it.

Comment: Be sure to add "... and here's an example from my past where I had to do exactly that."

Comment: @Jay, there is a difference between "Do you know?" and "How would you solve?".   The interviewer should be aware of this - we are talking about programmers here.

Comment: +1; I honestly would rather know that you can acknowledge you don't know something and can go figure it out (asking questions, Google, etc) in a somewhat methodical way (rather than flailing about).

Comment: +1 duh. this is what you say **anytime**, not just in interviews

Answer (score 18):

I will always say *"I don't know."* with confidence.

Here is an alternative that may play more into your favor. Like my previous idea say it with complete confidence.

> I am not familiar with that yet.

Comment: Highlighting **yet**. Always looks good if you act like you can learn it

Comment: *Act* like you can learn it? If you're a programmer who *can't* learn, you're in the wrong industry. :)

Comment: "I am not familiar with that yet" sounds weak to me, and like the person is trying to weasel their way out of something. Just be up front and dont talk like a politician.

Comment: @GrandmasterB - You can believe that but in practice it doesn't work. I've been on both sides of the process and you have to play the game or be played. Wording plays a huge role in how these things go.

Comment: You're not the only one here who runs interviews, and if a candidate starts using corporate-weasel-phrases to sugar coat things, its a serious strike against them in my book.  That really sounds like a 'prepared' statement - and it is.  To me that shows a huge lack of confidence if someone needs to rely on such things, and an inability to give a direct answer.

Comment: I prefer "I don't know. I haven't had the opportunity to reasearch/look into [x] in depth yet."

Comment: Some people may think it sounds better to say "not yet", but the most straightforward interpretation of this phrase is that it is on the applicant's todo list. If I ask you whether you are familiar with an obscure and obsolete transmission protocol we use at my company and you say "not yet", I'm going to be confused. Why's that? You were just waiting for the next rainy day to leaf through a book on the subject??? Just admit ignorance. Follow up with a few insightful questions on the topic, assuming you can. This will demonstrate that you are curious about it and can learn it.

Answer (score 9):

We all have blind spots, so saying "I don't know" once, it's not a problem. Saying it many times probably won't get you a job, but there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Right and quite frankly if there are multiple "I don't know's" then the job may not be properly aligned with you.  Perhaps even better off not taking the job.  Interviews are good for both the employer and potential employee.

Answer (score 2):

Asking for clarification would be another possible route to take as sometimes questions can be restated to make it easier to answer.  That is what I would do if someone were to ask me about something where I don't even understand what is the question.

Answer (score 0):

"I have never worked with ????.  When i a had a problem that ???? solves, i instead used  (insert real example that relates to my resume here)"

Having every opportunity to prove that you are not lying about projects you worked on, can be much more powerful than knowing a detail

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you say, you should have two things there- honesty and confidence.

That's all I think.

Answer (score -2):

if you don't know anything about it, the best thing is to be transparent and admit that. this way you don't waste anyone's time.

but, you better know a little something about everything: and introduction or what's it about or at least the domain to what that question/technology belongs to or what's the reasoning behind the existence of that technology.

show the interviewer you know the world around you.

on the other hand, if you do know a little bit, start from there.

most interviewers will help you, and even provide and **explain** the answer. this is where it's important to not just play dead. ask questions and try to understand what he/she's saying. make sure you leave that interview with something new.

some people do care about your ability to understand things and about your attitude towards new stuff

Answer (score -2):

1) Can you help me out here by giving some hint.
2) I don't know what that is yet, but I think this is what it is.
3) I haven't heard of that yet.
4) Will you please elaborate more?

Answer (score -2):

When I *really* don't know the answer: "Honestly I don't know. But I'd be very interested to hear the answer."

It's a great way to bound with the interviewer since he/she is now the one under the spot. It shows that you're honest about your skills and eager to learn. Plus if the interviewer has difficulty answering his/her own question in a concise manner it may demonstrate the question isn't trivial.

Answer (score -2):

I feel a really important aspect to these questions is elaborating your thought process. I know that a lot of the interview questions I've had were purposefully designed so that it would be unlikely that I know the answer immediately.

I feel that it is very mature to admit that you do not know the answer, but you should follow through with a methodology for going about trying to solve the problem, just to show your analytical skills.

Answer (score -3):

Can I hop on google for a few seconds?  Because when I don't know the answer to something I just go and find the answer....this

Comment: Just my opinion, but I am a hiring manager so that must be worth something. I think this is a terrible answer. In fact I wrote a whole blog post about why it is a terrible answer (http://improvingsoftware.com/2009/05/15/why-id-just-google-it-is-not-an-acceptable-interview-answer/)

Comment: @JohnFx - As your blog post pointed out, though, it is not necessarily a UNIVERSALLY bad answer. Questions in interviews about minutiae like listing from memory all the various enumerations available for a particular method call of a class is one of those "lean on the IDE / Google it" appropriate times. If someone cannot explain what a CLASS is or how to write a JOIN? Agreed - that's a bust.

Comment: @Todd - BTW: I wasn't the downvote. I may not agree, but I don't think it is a bad answer to the question.

Comment: Okay. But if someone asked me that, I might say "yes", give them a keyboard and evaluate how quickly/well they found the answer. So be ready to do that.